# Protect Github branches from being deleted

Tags: github

It looks like the Github UI changed for settings/branches for a repo. I can no longer figure out how to prevent a branch from being deleted.

[image]

Does anyone know how to prevent a branch from being deleted? Aka, protect the branch?

Comment: The new UI is weird, I tried comma separated values, to separate the branch names and it said the rule was invalid.

Comment: What happens if you leave everything unchecked and just click `Create`? The default action of the branch protection rule should prevent the specified `master` branch from being deleted.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

By default if you create a `Branch protection rule` for any branch, it `Disables force-pushes to all matching branches and prevents them from being deleted`. So if you create a rule with the pattern `master`, it would prevent the `master` branch from deletion by default.

About how the rule pattern works, it uses `fnmatch` to match against any pattern provided to find out the branches to which the rule applies. For eg :

- Rule pattern as `*` would apply to all the branches
- Rule pattern as `release*` would apply to all the branches whose name starts with `release`

Currently I don't think you can set any single rule pattern on GitHub (I have tried) to match multiple branches like for eg `master` and `develop`, since ideally `{master,develop}` should match both the branches, but currently it doesn't, and according to the fnmatch documentation `{a,b} matches pattern a and pattern b if File::FNM_EXTGLOB flag is enabled`

Check out more details on the above on [GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-protected-branches/) and the [fnmatch documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html#method-c-fnmatch)

Comment: Can confirm you still can't match multiple, distinct branches